# Сортировка Django по количеству комментариев

Tags: python, django

У меня есть две модели:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField("Text", blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to="post_img", blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="post_like")

class PostComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="comments")  # Связь
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="comment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField("Text", max_length=1300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Далее мне требуется сортировать посты по количеству комментариев
Вопрос как это сделать через ListView
Начал делать вот так, но не могу понять как взять именно количество комментариев

```py
class PostMostCommented(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('?????')
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `Post.objects.all().annotate(cnt=Count('comments').order_by('cnt')`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В django orm нельзя использовать в запросе количество объектов связанной модели, предварительно не аннотировав к запросу. Поэтому был введен специальный объект [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8):

```
from django.db.models import Count
```

В вашем случае его можно применить так:

```
queryset = Post.objects.all().annotate(cnt=Count('comments').order_by('cnt')
```